# Deleting an answer should turn the button text to "Undelete Answer" in the flagged post que if it's the last delete vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, deleted-answers, flag-queue

I keep a check on the flagged posts regularly to accept and reject the flags, though, one thing bugs me is the *Delete Answer* button, because, even after casting a vote, it doesn't disappear.

What happens is say my vote was the last one to cast a delete vote, so when I click it does get deleted, but clicking it again, castes an undesired *undelete answer* vote... Flagging the post does reduce the opacity, but deleting an answer doesn't.

I know I should ignore pressing it again, but for some reason if the message box fails to open, I click the delete again, and I get a box saying that your *undelete vote has been recorded*

[image]

[image]

If I've cast a delete vote and it's the third one which makes final delete, the post should be disappeared than and there.

If status by design says that a user can cast an undelete vote from the flagged posts que *(Which I don't think it's a normal design)*, than atleast the text of the button should be changed to *undelete answer*

Comment: I would really like to know the reason for downvote :) as you don't agree with the feature request

Comment: Don't worry about DownVotes here on Meta. It just means people disagree with your suggestion. You proposed a feature request, so people will vote heavily (either way) as it could potentially affect a function on the site (good or bad - hence up/down votes)

Comment: FWIW, when a moderator deletes a post from the flags queue, it *does* change to an undelete button afterwards.

Comment: @James It's fine if people downvote :) am not here to gain reputation, but somethings are really worth mentioning if you don't like the suggestions.. it just helps things get better yea, I was uncomfortable with the button not disappearing so I thought lets put up on meta...